# Use custom App Shortcuts: Find "Menu Command" for Chrome switch to right/left Tab

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I want to add an additional key binding for Google Chrome. I want to switch between my Tabs not using (<kbd>Shift</kbd>)<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (really bad finger position) but use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>-></kbd> or <kbd><-</kbd>

I hope to achieve this using App Shortcuts in Keyboard-Settings. However, I need the "exact name of the menu command" which I don't know. How can I find out the exact menu commands in general and does anybody know the ones for my use case?

Comment: On my Mac, to switch between tabs in Chrome uses Shift+Option then either the --> or <-- keys.  What does that combination do for you?

Comment: @fbara: What do you mean by Option?

Comment: It's the key to the left of Command.  It might have 'alt' on it.  (I can't add the keyboard glyphs in the Comments section)

Comment: @fbara: Actually Shift + alt and arrow keys would be okay for me. But in my Chrome it does not do anything. Do you use some special version?

Comment: I'm using Version 52.0.2743.41 beta (64-bit).  However, the [Chrome site](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) indicates this combination should work with any version.  If it doesn't work, try reinstalling Chrome.  Maybe some other application took this combination from Chrome so reinstalling should help.  If this works, let me know and I'll add it as an answer to help others.

Comment: @fbara: Okay, got it. The combination is cmd+alt+arrow. Did not find that since spectacle is using the same for positioning windows

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd> to navigate between the tabs.